# aws php sdk, how to check if status is up

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using AWS PHP SDK. Would like to check if instance is up, if not I'll start it, if down I'll stop ip. Anyone knows how to check instance status using the PHP sdk?

Answer (score 0):

`AmazonEC2::describe_instances()` will return metadata about all of your instances, including running state. (EC2 hangs onto information about recently-terminated instances for a short period of time.)

If you have the instance's ID, you can filter the results by passing it to the `InstanceId` input parameter.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonEC2/describe_instances